# Differenze di uso tra "in genere" e "in generale"

Tags: word-usage, difference

Le espressioni "in genere" e "in generale" mi sono sempre sembrate molto simili. Non capisco bene le diverse sfumature di significato o le differenze di uso tra queste locuzioni. Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Comment: *In genere* è in opposizione a *in specie* (antiquato *in ispecie*).

Answer (score 4):

In genere: (locuzione avverbiale):

> - la **locuz. avv. in genere, che, come l’analoga locuz. in generale (di cui non è sempre sinon.),** significa «generalmente, senza scendere a particolari, di solito» e sim. (Treccani)
> - avv. generalmente, in genere, solitamente: generalmente vado a dormire verso le undici. (Dizionario corriere sera).

Il dizionario Treccani online dice che le due locuzioni non sono sempre sinonimi, mentre altri dizionari non fanno questa distinzione.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=generalmente%2C%20in%20genere%2C%20in%20generale&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgeneralmente%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20genere%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20generale%3B%2Cc0): mostra che *in genere, generalmente e in generale* sono tre espressioni molto usate. Non mi vengono in mente casi in cui non siano intercambiabili e, a mio avviso, sono sostanzialmente dei sinonimi.

Comment: In gener[al]e è meglio attivare "case insensitive" nell'Ngram Viewer - ma in questo caso non cambia quasi nulla.

Answer (score 2):

Per come la percepisco io, la differenza è che "in genere" sta per "solitamente".
"In generale" è il contrario di "nello specifico".
Potrebbe anche essere una differenza regionale, però, per esempio, direi: "in genere vado a dormire alle dieci"; "in generale l'esame è andato bene, ma io non l'ho passato", ma non li scambierei. "Generalmente" lo vedo sinonimo di "in genere".

Comment: Quindi associ "in genere" ad una misura temporale? **In genere i napoletani gesticolano molto mentre parlano**, però questa è proiettata sullo spazio delle 20 regioni

Answer (score -1):

"generalmente" ad esempio non si può usare se posto al seguito di un oggetto al quale si fa riferimento; es: "non amo gli slavi in genere" è ok, "...in generale" è sempre ok, ma "generalmente" non ci sta.

Comment: nel senso che generalmente è l’unico che si può usare solo all’inizio della frase; gli altri sono sempre intercambiabili.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4504)

Comment: Può anche essere usato a fine frase, non solo all'inizio.